# real time audioprocessing with Qt: how to prevent application from crashing?

Tags: c++, qt6

With the following code, I want to record a song with my microphone and listen to it in real time. I use the QAudioSink and QAudiosource classes. I derived the QIODevice class and instantiated a child class object that I open in ReadWrite mode. I launch QAudioSink when the m_buffer contains at least 88200 Byte, and so when I have recorded 1-sec of audio signal( which I would like to avoid, because the application does not work in real time anymore). I can listen to what I say with a delay of 1 sec, but the program doesn't react anymore as soon as readData is called with maxlen = 44100 or a value close to it (so Windows suggests to stop it). I also notice that during the execution, the program stops for a few milliseconds.

I think that the problem is in the readData function, but I can't recognize it.

My Question now is how to improve the code so that the program does not crash anymore?

Thanks very much

I'm on Qt6.4

the Code

**the daughter class of QIODevice**

***.h-file***

```
class MyioDevInOutFilt : public QIODevice{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyioDevInOutFilt(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen) override;
    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len) override;
    qint64 bytesAvailable() const override;
    qint64 size() const override { return m_buffer.size(); }

private:
    QByteArray m_buffer;
    qint64 m_pos = 0;
    bool  is_Sink_Started= false;

signals:
    void enug_Buffer_to_start_playin();
};
```

***.cpp-file***

```
qint64 MyioDevInOutFilt::readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen){
    qDebug()<< "In readData maxlen = " << maxlen;
    qint64 total = 0;
    if (!m_buffer.isEmpty()) {
        while (maxlen - total > 0) {
            const qint64 chunk = qMin((m_buffer.size() - m_pos), maxlen - total);
            memcpy(data + total, m_buffer.constData() + m_pos, chunk);
            m_pos = (m_pos + chunk);
            total += chunk;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

qint64 MyioDevInOutFilt::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len){

    qDebug()<< "In writeData len = " << len ;
    if(!len){
        qDebug() << "len" << len;
        return 0;
    }

    const int channelBytes = 2;
    const int sampleBytes = 2;
    const int numSamples = len / sampleBytes;

    int16_t *ptr = (int16_t*)(data); // do something with it and append the result in m_buffer

    QByteArray temp_ByteArray;
    temp_ByteArray.resize(len);
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i=i+1){
        temp_ByteArray[i] = data[i];
    }
    m_buffer.append(temp_ByteArray);

    if(!is_Sink_Started){
        if(m_buffer.size()>88200){
            emit enug_Buffer_to_start_playin();
            is_Sink_Started= true;
        }
    }
    return len;
}


qint64 MyioDevInOutFilt::bytesAvailable() const{
    //return m_buffer.size();
    return m_buffer.size() + QIODevice::bytesAvailable(); // what is right?
}
```

**The mainwindows**

***.h-file***

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_btn_start_clicked();
    void check_and_start(){
        qDebug()<< "In check_and_start" << "\tm_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state(); 
        if(!sinkstarted){
            sinkstarted =true;
            m_audioSink->start(m_iodevinoufilt);
            qDebug() << "\tm_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state(); 
        }
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QAudioSource *m_audioSource = nullptr;
    QAudioSink* m_audioSink;
    MyioDevInOutFilt *m_iodevinoufilt = nullptr;
    bool sinkstarted = false;
};
```

***.cpp-file***

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) , ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(44100);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);

    m_iodevinoufilt = new MyioDevInOutFilt();
  
    QAudioDevice info = QMediaDevices::defaultAudioInput();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
    }
    m_audioSource = new QAudioSource(info, format, this);

    QAudioDevice infoOut = QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
    }
    m_audioSink = new QAudioSink(infoOut,format,this);
    qDebug() << "m_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state(); 

    QObject::connect(m_audioSink, &QAudioSink::stateChanged, [=]( QAudio::State)
                                                                { qDebug()<< "\t\t\tIn lambda"<<m_audioSink->state(); });



}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

***and the MainWindows Slot***

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_start_clicked() {
   
    if(ui->btn_start->text() == "Start"){
        m_iodevinoufilt->open(MyioDevInOutFilt::ReadWrite);
        m_audioSource->start(m_iodevinoufilt);
        oStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        //m_audioSink->start(m_iodevinoufilt);

        QObject::connect(m_iodevinoufilt, &MyioDevInOutFilt::enug_Buffer_to_start_playin, this, &MainWindow::check_and_start);

        ui->btn_start->setText("Stop");
        qDebug() << "m_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state(); 
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "m_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state();

        m_audioSource->reset();
        m_audioSource->stop();
        m_audioSink->reset();
        m_audioSink->stop();
        m_iodevinoufilt->close()

        ui->btn_start->setText("Start");
       qDebug() << "m_audioSink->state() " << m_audioSink->state(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by getting a stack trace showing where the crash occurred -- once you know the exact line where the crash occurs, you can start figuring out *why* that line crashes.  If all you know is that a crash occurs, it's difficult to figure out why it's crashing and therefore difficult to know how to fix it.

Comment: Obligatory link to article on how to debug small programs:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/